# Formatting SQL expression for calculate field (management) tool?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, sql, fields-attributes, expression

I am trying to take the population census tract and calculate the percentage of population by each census tract in the field (Populati_2). To do this I'm creating a new field with the total sum of the population (pop).

To get the percentage I'm usingthe following expression on arcgis `[Populati_2] / [Pop] *100`. It works fine in arcgis but when I'm using it to calculate field management or python it just doesn't work.

I'm not sure how to format the expression, I have tried every single combination and it's just not working.

Here's part of the script:

```
arcpy.AddField_management(r"Results\popjoin.dbf", "Pop", "LONG", "", "", "5")
arcpy.AddField_management(r"Results\popjoin.dbf", "Pop2", "DOUBLE", "", "", "5")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(r"Results\popjoin.dbf", "Pop", summed_total)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(r"Results\popjoin.dbf", "Pop2", '''Populati_2] / [Pop] *100''')
```

This one gives me errors, but the following does not give me any errors but I get a 0 in every row instead of the calculation.

`expression = "!Populati_2! / !Pop! * 100"`

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(r"Results\popjoin.dbf", "Pop2", expression, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: There are a lot of examples here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field-examples.htm Look closely at your syntax.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing VB and python syntax. Field delimiters for VB are square brackets while Python is the bang.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the commands, be careful what is a **VBS** and what a **Python** command/expression.

```py
fc = "file_name"

# http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/82251/53268
summed_total = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "Populati_2") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        summed_total = summed_total + row[0]

arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "Pop", "LONG", "", "", "5")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "Pop", summed_total)

arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "Pop2", "DOUBLE", "", "", "5")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "Pop2", "!Populati_2! / !Pop! * 100", "PYTHON", "#")
```

If you have problems with the expression, you can always use the Field Calculate Toolbox to build your expression. See your old Result under `Geoprocessing -> Results`

[image: arcgis result]

With a double click on **Calculate Field** you can open the toolbox. Here you can use the expression builder (make sure you set Python as Parser):

[image: calculate field]

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure of the expression syntax, try the following:

1. Crate a module in ModuleBuilder, add the Calculate Field tool, define all parameters, and run the model.
2. If it runs successfully, export the model File>Export to python script
3. Use the python expression syntax from the exported .py from step 2 into your python Calculate Field statement